# Is it possible to link a namespace frome a developer org to a developer hub

Tags: salesforcedx, package, namespace, github, dev-hub

We currently have an unlocked package with a namespace linked to a developer edition hub since at the time we where not aware of the limitations. Since we have the limitation to only do 5 package releases every day we want to link the namespace to a partner org dev hub. Is this possible while maintaining the same namespace?

The only thing I could find that it is possible to link a namespace to several hubs.

1. Is it possible to unlink the namespace from the developer edition?
2. Is it possible to link the current namespace also to a partner org dev hub and on release the package info also gets updated in the developer edition?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to note that linking a namespace does not imply anything about ownership of packages and package versions that use that namespace.

You can link your namespace to an arbitrary number of Dev Hub orgs. However, doing so *does not* move your existing package or package versions from Dev Hub A to Dev Hub B. It is not currently possible to move your existing package between Dev Hubs.

You would therefore be starting a *new* package in your Partner Business Org if you go down this road.

Comment: What do you mean by starting a new package. Do you mean creating a new package (as in version) with the same namespace?

Comment: I mean a new package, with no relationship to the old one. I am not certain what the implications are for upgradeability with Unlocked Packages.